# Block storage rewrites

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

## Summary

> In a block storage system, new data is written in blocks. We are going to represent the flash memory as one sequential array. We have a list of block writes coming in the form of arrays of size 2: `writes[i] = [first_block_written, last_block_written]`.
>
> Each block has a rewrite limit. If rewrites on a block reach a certain specified threshold we should run a special diagnostic.
>
> Given `blockCount` (an integer representing the total number of blocks), `writes` (the list of block-write arrays of size 2), and `threshold`, your task is to return the list of disjoint block segments, each consisting of blocks that have reached the rewrite threshold. The list of block segments should be sorted in increasing order by their left ends.

## Examples

> For `blockCount = 10, writes = [[0, 4], [3, 5], [2, 6]]`, and `threshold = 2`, the output should be `blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold) = [[2, 5]]`.
>
> After the first write, the blocks `0, 1, 2, 3` and `4` were written in once;
>   After the second write, the blocks 0, 1, 2 and 5 were written in once, and the blocks `3` and `4` reached the rewrite threshold;
>   After the final write, the blocks `2` and `5` reached the rewrite threshold as well, so the blocks that should be diagnosed are `2, 3, 4` and `5`.
>   Blocks `2, 3, 4` and `5` form one consequent segment `[2, 5]`.
>
> For `blockCount = 10`, `writes = [[0, 4], [3, 5], [2, 6]]`, and `threshold = 3`, the output should be
>   `blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold) = [[3, 4]]`
>
> For `blockCount = 10`, `writes = [[3, 4], [0, 1], [6, 6]]`, and `threshold = 1`, the output should be
>   `blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold) = [[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 6]]`

## Constraints

- `1 ≤ blockCount ≤ 10**5`
- `0 ≤ writes.length ≤ 10**5`
- `writes[i].length = 2`
- `0 ≤ writes[i][0] ≤ writes[i][1] < blockCount`

## First try

```
from itertools import groupby

def group_blocks(num_writes, threshold):
    i = 0
    for key, group in groupby(num_writes, lambda x : x >= threshold):
        # This is faster compared to len(list(g))
        length = sum(1 for _ in group)
        if key:
            yield [i, i + length - 1]
        i += length

def blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold):
    num_writes = [0] * blockCount
    for lower, upper in writes:
        for i in range(lower, upper + 1):
            num_writes[i] += 1
    return list(group_blocks(num_writes, threshold))
```

Here I just do exactly what is asked, I create an array of blockCount size, loop over the writes and lastly group the consecutive ranges with `itertoos.groupby`

## After trying to optimize

I'm not quite sure what the complexity was, but I tried to lessen the load, yet I still didn't pass the TLE constraints

```
def get_bad_blocks(blockCount, writes, threshold):
    cons = False
    u = l = -1
    for i in range(blockCount):
        count = 0
        for lower, upper in writes:
            if lower <= i <= upper:
                count += 1
            if count >= threshold:
                if not cons:
                    cons = True
                    l = i
                    u = -1
                break
        else:
            u = i - 1
            cons = False

        if u != -1 and l != -1:
            yield [l, u]
            l = -1
    if cons:
        yield [l, i]


def blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold):    
    return list(get_bad_blocks(blockCount, writes, threshold))
```

## Questions

You can review any and all, but preferably I'm looking for answers that:

- Tell me if my first example is readable
- I'm less concerned about readability in my second try, and more interested in speed
- Please ignore the `PEP8` naming violations as this is an issue with the programming challenge site

Comment: I don't think it's possible to give an "answer" addressing the performance issue — your current algorithm is unsalvageable. Consider what would happen in a realistic scenario where `blockCount=1000000`. The very first thing you'd do is loop `for i in range(1000000)`! That *cannot possibly* be part of a valid solution. You need to come up with an algorithm that doesn't take `O(blockCount)` time.

Comment: The comment "should be faster compared to len(list(g))" makes me think you should be doing some performance tests :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone probably, but I fail to see how this can be done without looping over the entire blockcounts... hence the asking for a review.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I have tested that locally, it should be faster because it doesn't have to construct the list as far as I can tell

Comment: I don't have time to check now, but my guess is that you would want to use a (default)dict with only those blocks that are encountered in `writes`. If it is a starting block, add +1, if it's the end block, subtract 1. Then go over the values with `itertool.accumulate` to get the numbers of writes between blocks.

Comment: @Georgy That might be a good approach, but wouldn't it still be O(n**2) for looping over writes and then looping again with accumulate

Comment: @Ludisposed: You say Georgy's algorithm is `O(n**2)`... but what is `n`? There is no `n` in your problem statement. (This is a real hint, not merely pedantry. You have misled yourself by thinking in terms of an `n` that doesn't exist. Think in terms of variables that *do* exist, and see where it leads you.)

Comment: Also, I should add: two `O(n)` loops (once to loop over writes and once to accumulate) doesn't make an `O(n*n)` algorithm — it makes an `O(n+n) = O(n)` algorithm. Things become quadratic only when the loops are *nested* one inside the other.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Thnx for that! I am confusing myself thinking in Big O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off when you're optimizing code you need to know what to optimize. At first I thought the problem code was not the `groupby`, but instead the creation of `num_writes`. And so I changed your code to be able to find the performance of it.

```
import cProfile
import random

from itertools import groupby

def group_blocks(num_writes, threshold):
    i = 0
    for key, group in groupby(num_writes, lambda x : x >= threshold):
        # This is faster compared to len(list(g))
        length = sum(1 for _ in group)
        if key:
            yield [i, i + length - 1]
        i += length


def build_writes(block_count, writes):
    num_writes = [0] * block_count
    for lower, upper in writes:
        for i in range(lower, upper + 1):
            num_writes[i] += 1
    return num_writes


def blockStorageRewrites(blockCount, writes, threshold):
    num_writes = build_writes(blockCount, writes)
    return list(group_blocks(num_writes, threshold))


block_count = 10**5
writes = []
for _ in range(10**4):
    a = random.randrange(0, block_count)
    b = random.randrange(a, block_count)
    writes.append([a, b])


cProfile.run('blockStorageRewrites(block_count, writes, 10**4)')
```

Resulting in the following profile:

```
         200008 function calls in 25.377 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.002    0.002   25.377   25.377 <string>:1(<module>)
   100001    0.019    0.000    0.025    0.000 lus.py:10(<genexpr>)
        1   25.342   25.342   25.342   25.342 lus.py:16(build_writes)
        1    0.000    0.000   25.375   25.375 lus.py:24(blockStorageRewrites)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.033    0.033 lus.py:6(group_blocks)
   100000    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 lus.py:8(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000   25.377   25.377 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.007    0.007    0.033    0.033 {built-in method builtins.sum}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Changing the code as per [Georgy's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215355/42401#comment416517_215355) to:

```
def build_writes(block_count, writes):
    num_writes = dict(enumerate([0] * block_count))
    for lower, upper in writes:
        num_writes[lower] += 1
        num_writes[upper] -= 1
    return list(accumulate(num_writes))
```

Gets the following profile, which is orders of magnitude faster:

```
         200011 function calls in 0.066 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.002    0.002    0.066    0.066 <string>:1(<module>)
   100002    0.021    0.000    0.028    0.000 lus.py:10(<genexpr>)
        1    0.025    0.025    0.025    0.025 lus.py:16(build_writes)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.064    0.064 lus.py:24(blockStorageRewrites)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.036    0.018 lus.py:6(group_blocks)
   100000    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 lus.py:8(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.066    0.066 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        2    0.008    0.004    0.036    0.018 {built-in method builtins.sum}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: The `return list(accumulate(num_writes))` line should be `return list(accumulate(num_writes.values()))` else I'd be accumulating the keys. Other then that, this is a great teaching moment for me. I should know what the bottlenecks are before optimization :)

Comment: And I did had to do `(block_count + 1)` and `num_writes[upper + 1] -= 1` to make the upper bound work correctly

Comment: @Ludisposed Ah oops :( My main aim was to show how to go about improving performance, so I didn't test at all.

Comment: No problem, as the "You should have profiled the code before starting to optimize" was the (for me) important part of the answer. I do wonder did you find any other mistakes, simplifications or just quit after profiling?

Comment: @Ludisposed I quit after profiling, but the first code looks good otherwise. If there wasn't a TLE then I'd say the original code is good and say to stop there. If there's another TLE then I'd look into it more, but I think 25 seconds -> 0.5 would mean there isn't one.

Comment: Thnx! One final note... just nitpicking here ;), that `dict(enumerate)` is superfluous the same can be achieved by a `list` -> `[0] * (block_count + 1)`

Comment: @Ludisposed Yes! Yeah I probably should have thought of that too >:( Also I don't think you need the `list` after the `accumulate`, as IIRC `groupby` works on iterators and iterables.